# Can a header slide under a sticky navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the heading to "slide" along under the navbar. But now it looks like the picture.
I have just started and would be very happy about some support. I already have some experience with HTML and CSS but now I don't know what to do.
My goal is to have the heading slide under the navbar.

sorry for the long CSS:)

HTML (shorted)

```css
        .nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        position: fixed;
        line-height: 65px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .nav div.logo {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding-left: 3rem;
    }

    .nav div.logo a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 3.5rem;
    }

    .nav div.main_list {
        height: 65px;
        float: right;
    }

    .nav div.main_list ul {
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav div.main_list ul li {
        width: auto;
        height: 65px;
        padding: 0;
        padding-right: 3rem;
    }

    .nav div.main_list ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 65px;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
    }

    /* Home section */

    .home {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url(./../img/hero.jpg);
        background-position: center-top;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    div.home h1 {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
        font-size: 15rem;
    }

    .navTrigger {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }
```

```html
 <nav class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">Leon Vu</a>
            </div>
            <div id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
                <ul class="navlinks">
                    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="navTrigger">
            </span>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: Website screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure if it is only me, but I can't see the image you are referring to.

Comment: Would you mind adding a working snippet to your question?

Comment: Anyone has a idea?